# jqTouch Swipe not working on native browser

Tags: android, mobile, jqtouch

It seems swipe does not work with the native browser nor the webview, whereas it works perfectly with Chrome (desktop and mobile).

This is the code I used for testing purpose:

```
$('#myPage').swipe(function(event, info) {
    console.log('Swipe detected on #myPage: '+info.direction);
});
```

I don't have any error showing up.

`FastTouch:false` does not fix this behavior.

```
var jQT = $.jQTouch({
    useFastTouch: false
});
```

Have you met a similar issue? How could I fix this?

Comment: I just had a similar issue with all touch events. var jQT = new $.jQTouch({useFastTouch: false}); right after loading the library solved the issue for me.